# Let f(x) be an irreducible over F

Tags: polynomials

What is multiplicity?
Let f(x) be an irreducible over F. then f(x) has a multiple roots if and only if f(x)'=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polynomial $p(X)\in F[X]$ ($F$ a field) has a root $\alpha$ if and only if $p(X)$ is divisible by $X-\alpha$. This root has multiplicity $m$ if $p(X)$ is divisible by $(X-\alpha)^m$ *exactly*, i.e. if it is divisible by $(X-\alpha)^m$, but not by  $(X-\alpha)^{m+1}$.

A criterion for $\alpha$ to be a root of $p(X)$ with multiplicity $m$ is that
$$p(\alpha)=p'(\alpha)=\dotsm=p^{(m-1)}(\alpha)=0,\enspace\text{but }\quad p^{(m)}(\alpha)\neq 0.$$